# Javascript match two arrays by id

Tags: javascript

The goal is to match two arrays by id. I need to check if `stopId` is in both `info` and `times` arrays and combine matching arrays.

What should be the proper check to find out if id matches? I've attached an example, I was trying to implement using `includes`.

Could you please give me an advise?

```html
const info = [
  {
    stopId: 1,
    name: "N1"
  },
    {
    stopId: 2,
    name: "N2"
  },
    {
    stopId: 3,
    name: "N3"
  }
]

const times = [
  {
    stopId: 1,
    time: "T1"
  },
    {
    stopId: 3,
    time: "T2"
  }
]

// Expected
// [
//   {
//     stopId: 1,
//     name: "123",
//     time: "T1"
//   },
//     {
//     stopId: 2,
//     name: "123"
//   },
//     {
//     stopId: 3,
//     name: "123",
//     time: "T2"
//   }
// ]



const res = () => {
  const final = [];
  
  info.forEach((item) => {
     if (times.includes(item.stopId)) { // How to check if stopId matches
       final.push({  })
     }
  })
}

console.log(res())
```

Comment: `const combined = info.map(i => ({ ...i, ...times.find(t => t.stopId === i.stopId) }))`

Answer (score 0):

With `includes` you are comparing the objects of *time* to the *stopId* of the *item*. You have to select the stopId of the time first. You can use the operator `find` for example:

```js
info.forEach((item) => {
     if (times.find(t => t.stopId === item.stopId)) {
       final.push({  })
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const result = info.map((item) => {
  const time = times.find((time) => time.stopId === item.stopId)
   return {
     ...item,
     time: time ? time.time : null
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached a working example

```js
const info = [{
    stopId: 1,
    name: "N1"
  },
  {
    stopId: 2,
    name: "N2"
  },
  {
    stopId: 3,
    name: "N3"
  }
]

const times = [{
    stopId: 1,
    time: "T1"
  },
  {
    stopId: 3,
    time: "T2"
  }
]

// Expected
// [
//   {
//     stopId: 1,
//     name: "123",
//     time: "T1"
//   },
//     {
//     stopId: 2,
//     name: "123"
//   },
//     {
//     stopId: 3,
//     name: "123",
//     time: "T2"
//   }
// ]



const res = () => {
  const final = [];

  info.forEach((item) => {
    let temp = { ...item
    };
    times.forEach((el) => {
      if (item.stopId === el.stopId) {
        temp = { ...temp,
          ...el
        };
      }
    })
    final.push(temp);
  })
  console.log(final);
}

res()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You should try this code 
var record1 = [
    {
        id: 66,
        name: 'haris'
    },
    {
        id: 873,
        name: 'laxman'
    },
]

var record2 = [
    {
        id: 99,
        name: 'arjit'
    },
    {
        id: 873,
        name: 'laxman'
    },
]
var result = record1.filter((elem, index) => elem.id == record2[index].id );
```